# Console error after successfully compiling TS files to JS and bundling with webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, three.js, typescript-typings

I'm trying to use three.js with type definitions from NPM (@types/three) so that I can write some 3D stuff with intellisense. I have one Typescript file like this:

```js
import * as THREE from "three";

let camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
let scene: THREE.Scene;
let mesh: THREE.Mesh;
let renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer;

function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / 
    window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
    camera.position.z = 1;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    let geometry: THREE.BoxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
    let material: THREE.MeshNormalMaterial = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
animate();
```

Now that's basically same as the example here (https://www.npmjs.com/package/three) except in TS instead of JS.

In addition here's my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "orbital",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "ThreeJs software to simulate orbitals.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compilets": "node node_modules\\typescript\\lib\\tsc",
    "webpackbuild": "webpack --mode development --entry ./main.js --output ./index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "three": "^0.98.0"    
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.26.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.10",
    "@types/three": "^0.93.10"
  },
  "author": "My name",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Here's my tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {    
    "target": "es5",                          
    "module": "es2015",                     
    "strict": true,                         
    "esModuleInterop": true                 
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "models"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

So the problem is that when I first run `npm run compilets` it compiles all my ts files to js files (I didn't install Typescript globally and that's why I have to refer tsc like so). Then when I run `npm run webpackbuild` it runs without any error and bundles all stuff into index.js. Now when I'm trying to run that in browser (I have very simple HTML page that just calls index.js) I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object../node_modules/three/build/three.module.js (index.js:109)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:20)
    at eval (main.js:2)
    at Module../main.js (index.js:97)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:20)
    at index.js:84
    at index.js:87
./node_modules/three/build/three.module.js @ index.js:109
__webpack_require__ @ index.js:20
(anonymous) @ main.js:2
./main.js @ index.js:97
__webpack_require__ @ index.js:20
(anonymous) @ index.js:84
(anonymous) @ index.js:87
```

Am I using types somehow wrong there or what might be the issue? Any help is appreciated and I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: On a side note: move typescript and the two types to your devDependencies. Because they do not need to be compiled.

Comment: @Silvermind Thanks for the tip. I did the change and also updated my original post to match current state. Not that it had any effects but still :)

Comment: that does not make any difference. devDeps and deps don't make a difference when you are not developing a library to be published on npm

Comment: and @types are omited by ts anyways

Comment: Could you go through the compiled `index.js` file and let us know what's happening at line 109?

Comment: @Marquizzo Here you can find the whole compiled index.js https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai6fbuigY-m3vjv4PDhhqBOeaOJU 109 refers to last eval() statement, but I don't know if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I found the answer which turned out to be very simple though very hard to catch / notice. It's just that my three.js library didn't match typings versions. I downgraded three.js to 0.93 and now it works. Right now @types/three is at 0.93 so I guess I have to use that version until they are updated.